# I'm trying to write a personclass and a personTester in Java

Tags: java, tostring

So far for my personClass, I have the following:

```
package personclass;

public class Personclass {
private static boolean Personclass;
private int PersonCount;
    public int getPersonCount()
    {
        return PersonCount;
    }

    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;
    private int Age;
    private Double Height;
    private String Gender;

    public Personclass(String foreName, String surName, int age, Double height, String gender)
    {
        FirstName = foreName;
        LastName = surName;
        Age = age;
        Height = height;
        Gender = gender;
    }

    private String getFirstName()
        {
    return FirstName;
}

private void setFirstName(String foreName)
{
    this.FirstName = foreName;
}

private String getLastName()
{
    return LastName;
}

private void setLastName(String surName)
{
    this.LastName = surName;
}

private int getAge()
{
    return Age;
}

private void setAge(int age)
{
    this.Age = age;
}

private Double getHeight()
{
    return Height;
}

private void setHeight(Double height)
{
    this.Height = height;
}

private String getGender()
{
    return Gender;
}

private void setGender(String gender)
{
    this.Gender = gender;
}

/**
 *
 * @param FirstName
 * @param LastName
 * @param Age
 * @param Height
 * @param Gender
 */
public Personclass(String FirstName, String LastName, int Age, double Height, String Gender)
{
    this.FirstName = FirstName;
    this.LastName = LastName;
    this.Age = Age;
    this.Height = Height;
    this.Gender = Gender;
            ++PersonCount;
}

/**
 *
 * @return 
 */

@Override
public String toString()
{
        return "Person[forename=" + getFirstName() + ", surname=" +  getLastName() +  ", age=" + getAge() + ", height=" + getHeight() +"m" + ", gender=" + getGender() +"]";
}
public String format()
{
        return String.format("%10s %10s %10d %10.2f %10s", getFirstName() , getLastName() , getAge() , getHeight() , getGender());
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

}
}
```

And for my personTester, I have the following code:

```
package personclass;

public class PersonTester
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

        Person person1 = new Person("Joe","Smith",25,1.57,"Male");

        Person person2 = new Person("Sain","Davies",18,1.73,"Female");

        Person person3 = new Person("John","White",22,1.60,"Male");

        Person person4 = new Person("Martin","Taylor",26, 1.54,"Male");

        Person person5 = new Person("Jessica","Clarke",19,1.70,"Female");

        System.out.println(person1.toString());
        System.out.println(person2.toString());
        System.out.println(person3.toString());
        System.out.println(person4.toString());
        System.out.println(person5.toString());

}
}
```

The thing that I'm having trouble with is not being about to print anything out when I try and run the personTester. How would I go about trying to print the five different people out?

Comment: You have two `main` methods. A program should only have one. Try removing the one in `Personclass.java` or explicitly execute the other by selecting the class before running.

Comment: Add proper indentation

Comment: Where is the `Person` class?  I see a `Personclass` class and a `PersonTester` class.

Comment: You should follow Java Code convention first at all. You have a static field with the same name as the class name.

Comment: i recommend you to read java naming convention  http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Comment: Dude, create an account.  It appears you've already caused the creation of two anonymous accounts: one to ask and one to re-edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the objects in main() in class PersonTester type Personclass.  That should enable you to print the information about the people, through the toString() method in that class.

Comment: If this would be the problem then there would be at the very least some output: either the person objects or the exception details.

Comment: Presumably, then, the person wrote a class Person.  I'm not convinced they need it, though.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two possible solutions.

1. You should make sure that you are running the `PersonTester` class, but not `Personclass`. i.e., You should be using `java PersonTester` command if you are running from command line.
2. The name of your class is `Personclass` but in your `PersonTester` class, you are referring to some `Person` class. You should change the `Personclass` to something like the following.

   package personclass;

   ```
       public class PersonTester{

         public static void main(String[] args) {

               Personclass person1 = new Personclass ("Joe","Smith",25,1.57,"Male");
               Personclass person2 = new Personclass ("Sain","Davies",18,1.73,"Female");
               Personclass person3 = new Personclass ("John","White",22,1.60,"Male");
               Personclass person4 = new Personclass ("Martin","Taylor",26, 1.54,"Male");
               Personclass person5 = new Personclass ("Jessica","Clarke",19,1.70,"Female");

               System.out.println(person1.toString());
               System.out.println(person2.toString());
               System.out.println(person3.toString());
               System.out.println(person4.toString());
               System.out.println(person5.toString());
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: You're saying exactly the same as the other answer, so I'll comment again: if this would be the problem then there would be at the very least some output: either the person objects or the exception details.

Comment: Who knows how the Person.toString method is defined. If the toString() method in the Person class returns "", there would be no output :)